Efficiently creating python dict from protobuf deserialized message
I want to compare the performance of some json alternatives in Python. I set up a test as follows, comparing the stanadrd json library with orjson and protobuf.
import orjson
import json
import time
import sys
import message_pb2
from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
print(f"This should be 'upb': {api_implementation.Type()=}\n")


message = message_pb2.ChatMessage()
parsed_message = message_pb2.ChatMessage()

message.sender = "Test Name"
message.active_connections = 40
message.memory_usage = 0.554781258874
message.data.extend(["Hammer", "Radio"])

x = {
  "name": "Test Name",
  "age": 40,
  "random_float": 0.554781258874,
  "items": ["Hammer", "Radio"]
}

NUM_TESTS = 1000000

def perf_tests():
    # Protobuf
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        binary_data = message.SerializeToString()
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    proto_serialize_time = (t1 - t0)*1000
    print(f"\nProtobuf serialize:   {proto_serialize_time:,.0f} ms")

    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        parsed_message.ParseFromString(binary_data)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    proto_deserialize_time = (t2 - t1)*1000
    print(f"Protobuf deserialize: {proto_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Protobuf total:       {proto_serialize_time + proto_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Protobuf file size:   {sys.getsizeof(binary_data)} b")

    # Orjson
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        x_dump = orjson.dumps(x)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    orjson_serialize_time = (t1 - t0)*1000
    print(f"\nOrjson serialize:     {orjson_serialize_time:,.0f} ms")

    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        x_1 = orjson.loads(x_dump)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    orjson_deserialize_time = (t2 - t1)*1000
    print(f"Orjson deserialize:   {orjson_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Orjson total:         {orjson_serialize_time + orjson_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Orjson file size:     {sys.getsizeof(x_dump)} b")

    # Json
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        x_dump = json.dumps(x)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    json_serialize_time = (t1 - t0)*1000
    print(f"\nJson serialize:       {json_serialize_time:,.0f} ms")

    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        x_1 = json.loads(x_dump)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    json_deserialize_time = (t2 - t1)*1000
    print(f"Json deserialize:     {json_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Json total:           {json_serialize_time + json_deserialize_time:,.0f} ms")
    print(f"Json file size:       {sys.getsizeof(x_dump)} b")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    perf_tests()


When I run the test like that, I get the following results:
Protobuf serialize:   403 ms
Protobuf deserialize: 344 ms
Protobuf total:       747 ms
Protobuf file size:   64 b

Orjson serialize:     407 ms
Orjson deserialize:   645 ms
Orjson total:         1,052 ms
Orjson file size:     116 b

Json serialize:       3,588 ms
Json deserialize:     2,630 ms
Json total:           6,219 ms
Json file size:       132 b

This is all as expected - standard json library is the slowest, orjson is much faster than json with a small reduction in filesize, and protobuf is the fastest while also having a much smaller filesize.
However, the deserialized data that I get is still a protobuf message type. Any attempt that I make to convert it to a dictionary absolutely destroys the performance. Using MessageToDict makes deserialization go from 344 ms to around 12,000 ms, which is worse than the standard json library.
Building a dictionary manually using the message object attributes still pushes the deserialization time to around 1,000 ms, so once again it loses to orjson.
x_dict = {
            "name": parsed_message.sender,
            "age": parsed_message.active_connections,
            "random_float": parsed_message.memory_usage,
            "items": parsed_message.data,
         }

For my application messages have several optional fields so I would have to build several different manual dictionary builders which would not be ideal. I like the reduction in filesize, but I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a better and more performant way of doing this, unless I'm missing something?

"Efficiently creating python dict" This is the problem. Each dict object contains 10 objects that needs to be allocated, filled, reference counted, freed. Assuming allocating a node take only 20 ns and freeing takes about the same time, then the whole operation will take at least 1_000_000 * (10+1) * (20+20) = 0.44 second just for the malloc/free. On top of that, there are type checking and possibly parsing overheads. All of this is partially what makes (C)Python so slow. Creating 1_000_000 dict objects cannot be efficient (though possibly faster than what you get).

Be aware that a list of dictionaries is generally a very inefficient data representation for similar objects having the same keys (especially in Python). A dataframes is far better suited for that. They do not needs objects to be hashed, contain 1 header for all the lines as opposed to 1_000_000 repeated strings, enable vectorized operation, can compact columns in native arrays so to massively reduce the memory overhead, are more cache friendly since data is accesses in a more predictable manner. Not to mention they are more safe since all items of a row is guaranteed to have the same type.

If you plan to operate on 1 object at a time, then you can recycle it by mutating only the values and not the key. This avoid allocating/freeing 5 objets/dict here (i.e. 5_000_000 malloc/free). You can even possibly recycle the list object.

Hi Jérôme, thank you for your detailed reply. Apologies for taking so long to reply - life got in the way somewhat.
That's really interesting information - I've only worked with high level programming languages so far and I'm definitely appreciating how they have shielded me from a lot of the workings under the hood. I can see that I need to go and rethink my approach, and how I go about testing things.
Thanks again !
